# There is an error in XML document (0, 0) - Error Deserializing XML to object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

please advice how do i map the response into class because from every example i came across body always don't have symbol like `core:transactionResponse`

my code:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\GLResponseXml.xml";
        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

        var unwrappedResponse = xDoc.Descendants((XNamespace)"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" + "Body")
                                .First()
                                .FirstNode;

        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TransactionResponse));
        TransactionResponse response = (TransactionResponse)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xDoc.Descendants((XNamespace)"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" + "Body")
            .First()
            .FirstNode
            .CreateReader()
        );
```

for deserealizing this soap xml:

```xml
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:dpss0="bons">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <core:transactionResponse xmlns:bo="http://service.example.co.id/core/bo" xmlns:core="http://service.example.co.id/core">
            <response>
                <header>
                    <coreJournal>149326</coreJournal>
                </header>
                <content xsi:type="bo:OKMessage">
                    <message/>
                </content>
            </response>
        </core:transactionResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
```

but i got this error: `InvalidOperationException: <transactionResponse xmlns='http://service.example.co.id/core'> was not expected.`

i'm mapping the response into this class:

```
public class GLXmlResponse
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "response")]
    public class Response
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "header")]
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "content")]
        public Content Content { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "header")]
    public class Header
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "coreJournal")]
        public string CoreJournal { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "content")]
    public class Content
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "transactionResponse", Namespace = "http://service.example.co.id/core")]
    public class TransactionResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "response")]
        public Response Response { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "bo", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Bo { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "core", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Core { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "transactionResponse", Namespace = "http://service.example.co.id/core")]
        public TransactionResponse TransactionResponse { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Header", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public string Header { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soapenv", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Soapenv { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "soapenc", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Soapenc { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsd", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsd { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xsi", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Xsi { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "dpss0", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
        public string Dpss0 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

need help on getting the class object right

Comment: XmlRoot and XmlElement has a Namespace Attribute that need to be set.  It can be either a URL or an empty string "".  You may need to add the empty string to get you code working.  Xml Serialization is very hard to debug.  So what I normally do is start at root class and comment out all the properties in the class and get code working only with root.  Then slowly remove the comments to find out where the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro the exact error you're seeing, so you might want to check from a minimal repro; I'm using:

```cs
var env = (GLXmlResponse.Envelope)new XmlSerializer(typeof(GLXmlResponse.Envelope))
    .Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));        
System.Console.WriteLine(env.Body.TransactionResponse.Response.Header.CoreJournal);
```

where:

```cs
string xml = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:soapenc=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:dpss0=""bons"">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <core:transactionResponse xmlns:bo=""http://service.example.co.id/core/bo"" xmlns:core=""http://service.example.co.id/core"">
        <response>
            <header>
                <coreJournal>149326</coreJournal>
            </header>
            <content xsi:type=""bo:OKMessage"">
                <message/>
            </content>
        </response>
    </core:transactionResponse>
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
```

which just has a `null` for `.Response`. The reason for *that* is that this is actually in the empty namespace (prefixes are not inherited), so you need

```cs
[XmlElement(ElementName = "response", Namespace = "")]
public Response Response { get; set; }
```

However, this then causes a problem with the `OKMessage` in the xml. If I *comment out the `<content>`*, then it works and I can see the output `149326`.

However, it might be simpler to start by just copying the xml into the clipboard, Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes, and see what it generates, and work from there.

Comment: i'm still getting the same error with paste special xml generated class